# what to do when flyway update to 4.0 fails midway

Tags: flyway

I  tried to update my (Oracle) database to Flyway 4.0 from Flyway 3.x today. I can see the update script tries to remove a couple of indexes (`_vr_idx` and `_ir_idx`). The problem I'm facing is the update has failed mid-way and now every time I rerun it, it complaints about the indexes not existing...

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue fixed in the upcoming Flyway 4.0.1.

In your case you have 3 options:

1. Drop the schema_version table and baseline the schema with Flyway 4.0
2. Manually perform the remaining actions on the schema_version table, followed by repair with Flyway 4.0
3. Recreate the dropped indexes and try again with Flyway 4.0.1

Comment: Thanks, just out of curiosity now:

Why would the update script fail with a "_ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired_". The Flyway metadata table doesn't have many entries and there shouldn't be any contention for it. Is the script trying to lock down the whole database?

Comment: No it isn't. Must be something else in your Oracle instance causing this to fail.